# Has no Package.swift manifest for version error

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift-package-manager

I need to distribute xcframework by SPM.
I had followed Apple guideline:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/distributing_binary_frameworks_as_swift_packages
I'm facing the following problem, when I'm trying to add dependency to the consumer app, the following error occurs:

> https://github.com/mygithub.git has no Package.swift manifest for
> version 0.0.1 in https://github.com/mygithub.git

But the file Package.swift exists in the root of the repository.
Does anyone has any idea how to fix this error?

P.S. The Package.swift file is in the root directory.

Comment: Did you find any answer?